# capture video and audio from webcam locally?

Tags: apache-flex, webcam, video-capture, flex4.5

I'm writing a flex 4.5 application that's supposed to capture a video from a webcam and audio from microphone and save it in some video format (i don't care which format).

I use VideoDisplay to display the webcam. how can I fetch and play audio in real time ?

Is there a way to save the video locally without using a flash media server?

Comment: The audio can be accessed via the `flash.media.Microphone` class.  I'm also looking for a way to archive the a/v streams locally in an AIR app, so I'm hoping someone has a good answer for you on this one... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash/Flex does not have video encoding capabilities.  You will need to send to a server for the encoding.

Sorry, I know this isn't good news.  :\

Comment: Are you sure that's true?  If you create a NetStream with the camera and microphone attached to it, it sends (IIRC) a perfectly viable h263 stream to the endpoint - if there was a way to set an event to catch the data in the buffer for the NetStream and write it to a FileWriter, I would think that it would accomplish the goal.  I just haven't found a way to do that :/

Comment: He's right, it can't do it right now within installing a 3rd party local 'server' and streaming the data to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the red5Recorder which is a player built using flex builder and configurable to any recorder like Red5 server or Flash FMS. You can check with the open source code to understand that.